# Two paginations on one page YII2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I can’t do two paginations on one page. I have a page in the form of tabs, and each tab has a list of different products, I want to paginate each list
Here is the error code and screenshot

```
$posts = Wishlist::find()->where(['user_id'=>$id]);
$pagination =new Pagination([

    'defaultPageSize' =>10,
    'totalCount' => $posts->count()
]);

$posts = $posts->offset($pagination->offset )->limit($pagination->limit)->all();


$favs = FavLists::find()->where(['user_id'=>$id]);
$pag_favs =new Pagination([

    'defaultPageSize' =>10,
    'totalCount' => $favs->count()
]);

$favs = $favs->offset($pag_favs->offset )->limit($pag_favs->limit)->all();


    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'posts' =>$posts,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'favs' =>$favs,
        'pag_favs' => $pag_favs
    ]);
```

In view 1st pagination

```
          echo LinkPager::widget([
             'pagination' => $pagination,
          ]);

          ?>
```

In view 2nd pagination

```
<?php 

          echo LinkPager::widget([
            'pag_favs' => $pag_favs,
          ]);

          ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `pag_fvs` with `pagination` in LinkPager. LinkPager don't have property `page_fvs`.[Pagination](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager#$pagination-detail)

Comment: thx , its work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `pag_fvs` with [pagination](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-linkpager#%24pagination-detail) in LinkPager. LinkPager don't have property `page_fvs`.

```
<?= LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pag_favs,
]) ?>
```